# Is the provider and uid stored somewhere even after deleting a user using Devise and Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

Is the provider and uid stored in another table after deleting a user using Devise and Omniauth?

In my Rails 4 app I was trying to integrate Omniauth-facebook with Devise, following the [Devise and Omniauth Overview Guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)

I successfully logged in (and create an account) with my facebook account. Then as another admin user, I deleted the account used to signup with Facebook.

I tried to log in with Facebook (to recreate my account) with the same facebook account, and this time I was redirected to the regular email sign up page.

I went in my Rails Console and checked if there are any users using my facebook provider and UID and found an object `ActiveRecord::Relation`

```
2.1.3 :001 > user = User.where(provider: "facebook", uid: 'MYFACEBOOKUID')
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "users"."uid" = 'MYFACEBOOKUID'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

I believe this ActiveRecord::Relation, was not destroyed when I deleted my account using Facebook. And now it prevents me from signing up with my Facebook account.

How can I delete this relation?

My User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify before_add: :before_add_method
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

   before_create :set_default_role

   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
       user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
       user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
       user.username = auth.info.nickname
       user.facebook_page = auth.extra.raw_info.link
       user.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender
     end
   end

    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
      super.tap do |user|
        if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
          user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
          user.first_name = data["first_name"] if user.first_name.blank?
          user.last_name = data["last_name"] if user.last_name.blank?
          user.valid?
          # user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
      end
    end

   private

   def before_add_method(role)
    # do something before it gets added
   end

   def set_default_role
     if User.count == 0
       self.add_role :admin
     else
       self.add_role :user unless User.count == 0
     end
   end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relations to delete, the result is empty. You need to debug to find out why was the new user not saved.

#### In your controller use the following for debugging:

```
puts request.env["omniauth.auth"]
puts @user.errors.to_a
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, these will help. I commented out the line ```user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]``` from the controller,changed the omniauth scopes to only use ```email and default``` (I think the offline_access scope doesn't work anymore), and restarted the server. Now the registrations work.